# google app engine + python: uploading to blobstore causes wrong encoding

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I tried to upload blobs to Google App Engine's blobstore using the following HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>
<form id=upload action={{upload_url}} method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  Name: <input type=text name=name>
  Your photo: <input type=file name=image required=required><br><br>
  <input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The value of the template variable {{upload_url}} is obtained by `upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')` on the server side. The post-handling script is as follows:

```
    class Test(ndb.Model):
        name = StringProperty()
        image = StringProperty()

    test = Test()
    test.name = self.request.get('name')
    image = self.get_uploads('image')[0]
    test.image = str(image.key())
    test.put()
```

Usually, the `name` field will be filled with non-English characters (E.g., Chinese). The above programs works fine on my local SDK. However, the `name` is incorrectly coded when the program is run on Google App Engine. What's the problem then?

Comment: try: test.name = self.request.get('name').decode('utf-8')

Comment: Well, error message: ``UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u6211' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)``

Comment: You can try to upload without the upload_url and redirect, to find the encoding problem. Have a look at gcs_upload.py in this gist: https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that this is an old bug for years, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749&can=1&q=blobstore&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component). There are two solutions:

(1) Add the following statements into app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: webob
  version: "1.2.3"
```

(2) Add the file appengine_config.yaml with the following content:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from webob import multidict

def from_fieldstorage(cls, fs):
    """Create a dict from a cgi.FieldStorage instance.
    See this for more details:
    http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749
    """
    import base64
    import quopri

    obj = cls()
    if fs.list:
        # fs.list can be None when there's nothing to parse
        for field in fs.list:
            if field.filename:
                obj.add(field.name, field)
            else:
                # first, set a common charset to utf-8.
                common_charset = 'utf-8'
                # second, check Content-Transfer-Encoding and decode
                # the value appropriately
                field_value = field.value
                transfer_encoding = field.headers.get('Content-Transfer-Encoding', None)
                if transfer_encoding == 'base64':
                    field_value = base64.b64decode(field_value)
                if transfer_encoding == 'quoted-printable':
                    field_value = quopri.decodestring(field_value)
                if field.type_options.has_key('charset') and field.type_options['charset'] != common_charset:
                    # decode with a charset specified in each
                    # multipart, and then encode it again with a
                    # charset specified in top level FieldStorage
                    field_value = field_value.decode(field.type_options['charset']).encode(common_charset)
                    # TODO: Should we take care of field.name here?
                    obj.add(field.name, field_value)
    return obj

multidict.MultiDict.from_fieldstorage = classmethod(from_fieldstorage)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to put quotations around the meta tag parameter: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`?  Also, try: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`.  And, make sure you are saving your template's text document in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks. But HTML5 allows not to use quotations. So, for the sake of efficiency, I think it's better to reduce the size of HTML files.